# Как можно изменить цвет буквы?

Tags: java, android

Можно ли поменять цвет некоторых букв в самом `string.xml` или программно, как это можно сделать?

```
<string-array name="colors">
    <item>I read the letter.</item>
    <item>It is only with the heart that one can see rightl.</item>
    <item>One can become a writer only if he is talented.</item>
    <item>They say, the winter will be cold.</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<string-array name="colors">
        <item>
            <![CDATA[
               <font color="#005500">I</font> read the letter.
            ]]>
            </item>
        <item>It is only with the heart that one can see rightl.</item>
        <item>One can become a writer only if he is talented.</item>
        <item>They say, the winter will be cold.</item>
</string-array>
```

`Html.fromHtml(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors)[0])`

---

Программно:

```
final SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder("Text");
final ForegroundColorSpan style = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)); 
text.setSpan(style, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(text);
```